# delete rows from table where the columns are from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete

I'm having problems with my trigger, as I need to delete rows from one of my tables but the id's need to be left joined from that table to the data just inserted.

```
        DELETE FROM  TransactionTable where ItineraryReferenceNumber = 
        (select distinct i.ItineraryReferenceNumber from inserted i LEFT JOIN TransactionTable  FS 
        ON i.ItineraryReferenceNumber = FS.ItineraryReferenceNumber)
```

I need to get all of the records with the reference numbers matching it, which is why I am selecting them.

Is this correct, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If your subquery returns more than one value than you should use `WHERE ItineraryReferenceNumber IN (yourSubquery) `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in effect, just deleting records from the TransactionTable that are in your `inserted` table.

```
DELETE FROM TransactionTable 
WHERE ItineraryReferenceNumber IN (
    SELECT ItineraryReferenceNumber FROM inserted
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CustomerID FROM [Customers] where CUSTOMERID  NOT IN (SELECT O.CUSTOMERID from Customers c, Orders O where O.CustomerID=c.CustomerID)
```

See this sample code , from [this database](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_columns).
This is same query , as like you , this will return ID of customers who has not make nay orders. 
You can use same , you are deleting such ItineraryReferenceNumber where it match some criteria of another table.

Comment: @marchemike
Here , I have performed SELECT operation , you can use any operation. Let me know if you have any confusion.